# How to store the input correctly in MIPS?

Tags: mips

Although I have try to input different value ,but the Qtspim still print out the value"0" and the input is also not saved in the register ,I try to find the answer in internet,but it seem like no one have face this problem before.I do it work for 4hrs, I FEEL very frustrated with this.
here is my code ,I try to define whether the input is prime number or not.

```
# Power program
# ----------------------------------
# Data Segment
.data
request:             .asciiz "Enter an integer:"
Yes:                  .asciiz " is  a prime number.\n"
No:                   .asciiz " is not a prime number\n."
End:                 .asciiz"End!\n"
Key:                 .word -1
One:                 .word 1

# ----------------------------------
# Text/Code Segment

.text
.globl  main
 main:
    lw $t1,One
    add $s2,$zero,$zero
    lw $s3,One
    lw   $s0,Key
    add  $s5,$zero,$zero


j   power       # call the function power   

li  $v0, 10     # call code for exit
syscall         # system call
.end main


.globl  power


power:  

       j power_loop



power_loop:    
                   la   $a0, request    # load string request in memory to $a0
                   li   $v0, 4              # print out the string
                    syscall          #prevent Memory address out of bounds
                    li  $v0, 5
                    syscall
                    move $s7,$v0
                    beq $s7, $s0, exit_L    #when input =-1 exit
                    j        Prime                 #otherwise go to define the input whether prime num

Prime:  
       beq $s7,$t1,result   
       div  $s7,$t1
       mthi $t4
       beq  $t4,$zero,count
       addi  $t1,$t1,1
       j       Prime


count:    #counting the number of factors 
      addi $s2,1                            
      addi $t1,$t1,1

result:  addi $t1,$zero,1
       bne  $s2,$s3,resultNo
       beq $s2,$s3,resultYes




resultYes:  li         $v0,1
            move $a0,$s7
             syscall
             add $s2,$zero,$zero
             la      $a0,Yes
             li         $v0,4
              syscall
              j            power_loop
resultNo:    li         $v0,1
             move $a0,$s7
             syscall
             add $s2,$zero,$zero
             la   $a0,No
             li     $v0,4
              syscall
              j       power_loop
exit_L:       
              la    $a0,End
              li    $v0,4
             syscall
              jr       $ra


.end    power
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the behavior you describe. However, `mthi $t4` is obviously a bug (should be `mfhi $t4`). And the way you count how many numbers `$s7` is divisible by is broken; on the very first iteration you'll exit the loop because anything divided by 1 has a remainder of 0. Use the debugging features in the simulator to inspect your program's runtime behavior.

Comment: although I have change mthi to mfhi ,the result is still same to past,whatever I input , it just present 0 is a prime number in console,how can i fix it?

Comment: it seem like the program make my input become 0